# Please advise if there was a better way to play pocket T

Tags: texas-hold-em, strategy, heads-up

I have laid out the how I played the hand below, can you advise if there is a better way I could had played it? Thanks.

$0.10/$0.20 No Limit Hold'em Cash, 6 Players

**Preflop:**

Hero is UTG with T♦T♠
Hero raises to $0.60, MP folds, CO calls $0.60, 3 folds

**Flop:**

($1.50) Q♣Q♦K♦ (2 players)
Hero bets $1, CO calls $1

**Turn:**

($3.50) 2♦ (2 players)
Hero bets $1.75, CO calls $1.75

**River:**

($7) 8♣ (2 players)
Hero checks, CO checks

**Results:**

> $7 pot ($0.35 rake)
>
> Final Board: Q♣Q♦K♦2♦8♣
>
> Hero showed T♦T♠ and lost (-$3.35 net)
>
> CO showed K♣J♦ and won $6.65 ($3.30 net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you played this hand ok, the only thing I see a problem with is your bet on the flop.

This flop is a terrible one for TT, not only are there connected overcards here, but there is also a diamond draw. If you bet this flop, hands like JT, AJ, AT, Kx, Qx, and any 2 diamonds will always call. Most of the time if you get called you will be in bad shape or up against a drawing hand.

If you do decide to bet the flop, I would lean towards giving up and seeing if your opponent would check until showdown.

It is a very awkward spot, and there is not really any great course of action.

Answer (score 3):

TT, JJ, and QQ are all hard hands to play as you don't want to release them when you don't flop a set.

You had a flop with 2 over cards out of position. You have a blockers on the straight so I would not be worried about that. I get taking one shot at the flop but after that give up.  Or rep a Q and fire three times.  If you are going to bet the turn here you should bet the river.

Another option is to check the flop to represent a Q trapping.  Hopefully get to a cheap river and fire big.

Answer (score 3):

Preflop is ok.

Flop: I would prefer a much smaller flop bet ($0.55-$0.80) because a) TT has some showdown and im not looking to inflate the pot and b) OOP there are many bad turn/rivers, and not many good ones. A smaller bet can get ATo-AJo, maybe 88+ to call, which gives us some value. A flush draw, any K or Q is not folding to a 2/3 pot flop bet. I can see check/calling here to be a possible play as well, especially if you know your opponent tends to overbluff.

Turn: Turn fills the flush, meaning TT is now behind most of villian's flop calling range. I'm not even sure what i would be repping by betting the turn. Maybe any flush, AQ, KQ, QTs-QJs? I wouldnt be playing weaker Qs from UTG. AK i would probably go into check/call mode. Betting here turns TT into a bluff, which i wouldnt recommend. I imagine 9T, 9J, TJ with one diamond would be better bluff candidates here, because they are more likely to fold out better hands (88+), and have slightly more equity when called. Bluffing here means im preparing to bomb the river on any brick.

River: is a brick! Since our opponent didnt reraise on any street, im putting him on a hand that has reasonable value he wants to take to showdown, which makes checking here essentially giving up the pot. So i agree with Paparazzo that a bet (1-1.3x Pot) is a possible play, putting any K, or weak Q in a tough spot. A big bet here polarizes your hand which makes it harder for your opponent to call, and also harder for your opponent to reraise on a bluff. It also makes it much easier to lay down if your opponent does reraise the river. A river bet here also gives your turn bets more weight. If you have a tendency to check down the river after betting flop and turn, it gives your opponents an easier decision to call your turn bet down with marginal hands (such as KJo).

General: A good rule of thumb is to figure out whether youre betting for value (so worse hands call) or as a bluff (so better hands fold) on every street. Im not clear which you were going for in the hand above.